# Can I bruteforce adoptable-storage SD card to recover data?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, data-recovery, adoptable-storage, lg-g4

I got an LG G4  (locked bootloader, no root),  on which I enabled adoptable storage on with `adb` a few months ago.

Today, I tried to put a SIM card in the first SIM card slot, which was under the SD card slot (of course my phone was turned off). I removed the SD put the SIM in the other slot and put my SD card back in. Since my SIM card was the wrong size , I removed it. But when I turned the phone on , my SD card wasn't showing up. Even the file manager was not showing either my internal and my adoptable storage .  I tried to put another SD card , it didn't show up too. So, I think I damaged my SD card reader in some way. I know since device is not rooted I can't get the `.key` file to recover my SD card.

So my question is : Can I bruteforce the SD card to get the `.key` so that I can recover my data?

Comment: In theory , yes. In practice it may need huge resources and time. See [What if the FBI Tried To Crack An Android Phone? We Attacked One To Find Out](https://www.iflscience.com/technology/what-if-fbi-tried-crack-android-phone-we-attacked-one-find-out/). It may be easier to try data recovery services such as [EaseUS](https://www.easeus.com/storage-media-recovery/recover-data-from-encrypted-sd-card.html). I have no idea at all how much they cost and how effective they are

Comment: The problem with adoptable storage is you need the key... The key is 128-bit "code", the encryption itself is AES-256... So to brute force just the key is possible, but it could take 1 billion billion (1.02x10^18 to be more accurate) years with the most powerful supercomputer in existence today, because that equels 3.4x10^38 possible keys. In theory, you could get it right on your first try, but the reality is most cracks happen in 50% of the maximum time, so only 500 million billion years... We can't comprehend this kind of time, for example, the universe is ONLY 13.75 billion years old.